# How to calculate Total records Counts in table with my scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

I am Writing a SQL Code which basically count stars values Like ratings Feedback forms.To calculate how many peoples rate 
1 star,2,3 and so on i am using pivot unpivot SQL properties to calculate count against of each number hits.Now i want to calculate count of all records in the table along with my this query.
i want to achieve my desire result without sub-query.

```
    WITH survey AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                survey_id
            FROM
                survey_feedback
            WHERE
                survey_id = 1
            GROUP BY
                student_id,
                performance,
                teacher_behaviour,
                survey_id
        ) UNPIVOT ( star
            FOR q
        IN ( performance AS 'PERFORMANCE',
             teacher_behaviour AS 'TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR'
              ) )
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    survey PIVOT (
        COUNT ( student_id )
        FOR star
        IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
    )
ORDER BY
    q;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVCaI.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data *and* expected results as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB Dear Expect Result image has already attached above. i get total count of records in my table as the column name Total. it can easily achieve with subquery, but i want to get total count of my table without sub-query.

Comment: @GMB Inside Image You may see a column named as total which is the output getting from subquery to get count(*) of my table.i want such total count without any sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm not a fan of `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`.  They really offer no new functionality and are quite bespoke and not powerful enough.

So, I would just unpivot and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT survey_id, which, COUNT(rating) as total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_5
FROM (SELECT sf.*,
             (CASE WHEN which = 'PERFORMANCE' THEN performance
                   WHEN which = 'TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR' THEN teacher_behavior
              END) as rating
       FROM survey_feedback sf CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT 'PERFORMANCE' as which FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'TEACHER_BEHAVIOUR' FROM DUAL
            ) n
     ) sf
WHERE sf.survey_id = 1
GROUP BY sf.survey_id, which;
```

In Oracle 12C+, I would use a lateral join for unpivoting.

Comment: Thanks bro but i am using oracle 11g and when i will run this query it pops sf invalid identifier error.@Gordon Linoff                                                                                           
this error is happened ORA-00904: "SF": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 17

Comment: Error occured when execute this query.

Comment: @Faizan . .. You should set up a DB or SQL fiddle so it is clear what the original data looks like and I can see the error.  That said, the problem was probably just the missing table alias, `sf` in the subquery.

Comment: I have attached error summary in picture to clear error reason  what error has raised after changing the query